# Recording video with two audio channels

Tags: iphone, audio, video, headphones, microphone

I'm new to the filming/editing game and I am only equipped with my iphone 7+. I recently purchased a dual lightning adapter and Lavalier Lapel Microphone. I've started an ASMR channel that relies on delicate sounds + spoken word simultaneously

I was wondering if it was at all possible to have both the Lavalier mic and standard iphone headphones plugged in at the same time and have their own separate audios being recorded so that the video sounds layered?

I'm trying to avoid having to record voice-overs at a later time and I am worried about the voice taking precedence over sounds (or vice versa)

essentially, I am asking for the simplest way to have segmented sound and still use my phone.